# how to know which NSTextField has been modified its value

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield

I have several NSTextFields declared on my NSWindowController, all of them has as delegate the File's Owner, and respond fine to this method:

```
-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj{

}
```

but I also want to know the control's value for this I used next code

```
-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj{
    if ((NSTextField *)obj == self.nombreCuentaActivoTextField) {
        NSLog(@"you just edited nombreCuentaActivoTextField");
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, how to do that

Comment: You need to do somework on how to use controlTextDidEndEditing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj` is an `NSNotification`. You can't just cast it to an `NSTextField` and assume you've achieved anything useful.

The control which posted that notification and thus triggered that delegate method is the "object" of the notification. You can use `[obj object]` to obtain that. So, you might implement the method like so (I've renamed `obj` to `notification` for clarity):

```
-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification{
    if ([notification object] == self.nombreCuentaActivoTextField) {
        NSLog(@"you just edited nombreCuentaActivoTextField");
    }
}
```